# A Greedy Algorithm for Team Formation that is Fair over Time

Tags: combinatorics

I'm a programmer who can't read mathematical notation all that well. I've a problem which I believe I found a solution to in the following article, but I can barely understand any of the implementation with my limited math knowledge.

http://wwwhome.ewi.utwente.nl/~fokkinga/mmf2009l.pdf

The problem is: Distribute a set of people in a set of groups a certain amount of times, such that every person should work with everyone else at least once.

Anyone here who are willing to take a crack at helping me with an algorithm? Any programming language is fine.

Comment: Do the groups have be be specific sizes? Otherwise, $2$ groups of half of the people seems optimal to me. Probably it can be done in $\log_2(n)$ 'jobs'.

Comment: Ah, yes @Ragnar. The groups should be able to have specific sizes. To be very specific, I need to able to split 30 people into groups of 5, a total of 6 times. If it's a perfect world one should also be able to adjust group sizes individually in each iteration (though not a rule).